# How bind the NSXMLParserDelegate in C#

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am new to binding Objective-C to c#. I have following binding problems.

1)In monotouch i didn't found the NSXMLParserDelegate method.How to bind the NSXMLParserDelegate in C#.

```
  @interface interfacename : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate>{

       }
```

For above code how to bind the NSXMLParserDelegate in C#?

2)

```
 @protocol Delegatename <NSObject>

 -(void)protocolMethod;

  @end
```

For above code How to bind the Protocol declaration in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define the interface for the delegate, like this:

```
 [BaseType (typeof (NSObject)), Model]
 interface NSXMLParserDelegate { 
     // methods go here, empty will be fine as well
 }
```

Technically, you do not need this, unless you absolutely need to invoke the methods in the delegate yourself (which I put the chances of this being needed close to zero)